# php code to update other row order in database on removal of selected row

Tags: php, mysql

table name - News
column name - id,headline,send_sub_top,priority.

I am **inserting records in news table** and also **inserting max+1 value in priority column** with insertion of new records.

After that **updating the send_sub_top = Active from Activate button.**

**Now I need is when I click on row I need to update selected row column send_sub_top = '' and also update priority.**

**for example-- If I have 5 rows in database whose column send_sub_top = Active and priority like 1,2,3,4,5.**

**then IF I Remove row whose priority is 3 in database then other row priority will update like 1,2,3,4. not set like 1,2,4,5.**

plz help me

below is my code. plz suggest me how to update row priority priority counter in database

```
<!--script to update selected  news from SUB TOP section-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
            var del_id = $(this).attr('remove_sub_top_news');
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $.post('add_status_news.php', {remove_sub_top_news:del_id}, function(data){
            parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
        });
    });
});
</script>
<!--END-->


<div style="border:1px solid #000; float:left; width:400px; padding:5px 4px 5px 4px; height:225px">
    <div id="contentLeft1">
        <ul>            
        <?php                  
        foreach($sub_top_select as $sub_top) {                      
        ?>
            <li id="recordsArray1_<?php echo $sub_top['id']; ?>"><a href="javascript:return(0);" remove_sub_top_news="<?php echo $sub_top['id']; ?>">
                <img src="img/error.png" height="14px" width="14px" /></a>&nbsp;<?php echo $sub_top['headline']; ?></li>
                <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**php code to update on add_status_news.php page**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['remove_sub_top_news'])) {  
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['remove_sub_top_news'])));      
    $sql = "SELECT id,send_sub_top FROM news WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);        
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      
    mysql_query("Update news SET send_sub_top='' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['remove_sub_top_news']))));       
    if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {         
        $_SESSION['message'] = "News Removed From SubTop Successfully";
        header("Location:sethomepage.php");
        exit;
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: You could create a `TRIGGER`

Comment: Are you ok whit removing the other news from subtop? You got trouble only in updating the others rows?

Comment: yes..i only need to update other rows priority...

Comment: every thing is working fine i only need to update other rows priority in database when i removed and row..other rows will automatically update their priority....

Comment: as @Daan suggested i would create a Database Trigger for update Event. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is the nature of your problem...and solution.
Firstly, you need to let your database know the ID of the removed entry. Due to the nature of numbers (as per your description) everything BELOW the deleted ID doesn't need to change, but everything above needs to go down in value by 1

So if I understand you correctly, your code needs to look like this:

```
      /*sanitize AND set the $id in one pass*/
    if($id = intval($_POST['remove_sub_top_news'])) {  
        $sql = "SELECT id,send_sub_top FROM news WHERE id='$id' limit 1";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);        
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

    //get the priority of the current news item
    $target_priority = $row['priority'];

        mysql_query("Update news SET send_sub_top='' WHERE id=$id limit 1");       
        if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {         
            $_SESSION['message'] = "News Removed From SubTop Successfully";


    /*
    update priorities
    WHAT THIS IS DOING: 
    Using the priority of the currently item (the one you just "send_sub_top=''" on... as a 'cut off point' update all news items that have a priority higher than that item.
    So if it was priority 5,  for example, your priorities are now 1,2,3,4,6, 7, etc etc. So the query will update 6 and 7 and above by lowering them by 1, each...leaving you with 1,2,3,4,5 and 6.
    As this is repetitive, you could, as suggested above, use a trigger, but the logic is sound.
    */ 
    mysql_query("Update news SET priority=priority-1 WHERE priority > $target_priority"); 
header("Location:sethomepage.php");
            exit;
        }       
    }
```

Notes:

1. Note how I simplified your use of $id? By capturing the value AND
   sanitizing it in one go, you make your code cleaner, easier to read,
   and less prone to 'missing bracket' errors.
2. Notice the use of "limit 1" in the queries? Helps your mysql server know you only need
   one result so it should stop looking once one record is found.